# How Can I tag a Link using pdfbox for Accessibility?

Tags: pdf, accessibility, pdfbox

PDF document - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1I247aTij-3oPtdZmk43xQ8UcC8u2MliM/view?usp=sharing

above PDF has a link in it . I want to tag as Link for accessibility by using pdfbox.

Comment: Isn't this the same question as your other one?

Comment: Yeah, @Tilman. In another one(Older one) I'm creating the link and Here I want to tag an existing link for Accessibility.